# Why does __setattr__() not recurse when setting member array variable elements?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

Not sure if SO is the right place to ask but here goes...

I've been learning about [***`__setattr__()`***](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) and [***`__getattr__()`***](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and feel I understand the various recursion dangers, apart from when an element in a class instance array variable is set as there doesn't appear to be recursion in this case.

```
class Test(object):
    tableInfo = { 'table1' : {'col1' : 0, 'col2':1} }

    def __init__(self, tableName):
        super(Test, self).__setattr__('_tableName', tableName) # Must be set this way to stop infinite recursion as attribute is accessed in bot set and get attr
        self._rowData = [123, 456]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "# GETTING %s"  % (name)
        assert self._tableName in Test.tableInfo

        if name in Test.tableInfo[self._tableName]:
            return self._rowData[Test.tableInfo[self._tableName][name]]
        else:
            raise AttributeError()

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        print "# SETTING %s" % (name)
        if name in Test.tableInfo[self._tableName]:
            print "Table column name found"
            self._rowData[Test.tableInfo[self._tableName][name]] = val
            self._someAttr = 1
        else:
            super(Test, self).__setattr__(name, val)

class Table1(Test):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Table1, self).__init__("table1", *args, **kwargs)

t = Table1()
print t.col1
print t.col2
t.col1 = 999
print t.col1

t.dummy = 101
```

The example I was playing with is pasted below:

```
$ python test.py 
# SETTING _rowData
# GETTING col1
123
# GETTING col2
456
# SETTING col1
Table column name found
# SETTING _someAttr
# GETTING col1
999
# SETTING dummy
```

I can see that setting `col1` causes a recursion back into `__setattr__()` as I would expect due to the line `self._someAttr = 1`.

What I don't understand is why I don't see a similar recursion cause by the line `self._rowData[Test.tableInfo[self._tableName][name]] = val`.

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks...

Comment: The second snippet *doesn't set any attributes*; it gets the dictionary attribute, picks keys from it and uses the result to index a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, looking at the expression itself should answer your question:

`self._rowData[bla] = val` gets resolved to

- `self.__getattribute__("_rowData")[bla] = val`
- and then `self.__getattribute__("_rowData").__setitem__(bla, val)`

There is no further `__setattr__` called because no attribute is set in-between, you just change one.

Comment: Note that as `_rowData` already exists in instance dictionary due to `self._rowData` in `__init__` the next look ups to it won't call `__getattr__`(`__getattribute__` can find the attribute for us).

Comment: Gotcha... it was the setattr recursion I didn't understand: it was the resolution from `self._rowData[bla] = val` to `self.__getattribute__("_rowData")[bla] = val` and the use of `__setitem__` as opposed to `__setattr__` that I hadn't thought well enough about. Thanks for your help :)